# How can I have an Android application on top of another application, which controls the other applications GUI commands?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Is it possible to build an Android application (we can call it: OwnApp) that operates on top of another application (we can call it: OtherApp) in the following ways, without having access to the code of OtherApp:

- **Basic things** (Most important)
- Have a semi-transparent GUI in OwnApp that is put on top of the GUI of OtherApp.
- Have OwnApp automatically fill text boxes and click buttons in OtherApp.
- Have OwnApp read data from OtherApp.
- **Bonus things** (Less important, but would be nice)
- Have OwnApp control and/or capture the internet stream of packets of OtherApp.

What I basically want to do is build an app that can automate things on antoher app. So, can this be done? And how? I don't really care if I need the phone rooted or not.

Answer (score 2):

In Android, every app is considered as a different user in the linux os. What this basically means is that one app cant access the other app.

> How can I have an Android application on top of another application?

There is an absolutely interesting repo here which creates an application over another without affecting its activity lifecycle.

Have a look at this **STAND OUT LIBRARY** :

[Click here](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) .

Import the example to your workspace and run it.

Answer (score 0):

> Have a semi-transparent GUI in OwnApp that is put on top of the GUI of OtherApp.

You can use the WindowManager to inject Views over everything else. There are plenty of tutorials on this online.

> Have OwnApp automatically fill text boxes and click buttons in OtherApp.

This is not possible on Android.

> Have OwnApp read data from OtherApp.

If by data you mean saved persistent data, you can have the device rooted and then read internal memory. If by data you mean stuff currently on the screen, you can be rooted, take a screenshot from the framebuffer and run OCR on it. No other way besides this.

> Have OwnApp control and/or capture the internet stream of packets of OtherApp.

Have the user setup their device to send data through a proxy you own and monitor it. No other way.